# How to do a Trace request in postman

Tags: http, postman

I am trying to figure out how to do a trace request in postman. The available requests don't have an option to do a trace. Is there a way to currently turn that on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postman doesn't currently give you the ability to do this through the UI but as an alternative, you could use https://insomnia.rest/ which allows you to add a custom method to the normal list of verbs.

I've added the TRACE verb and tried to send a request to Google which returns a 405 status code.

[image: Example]

**Edit**:

The latest version of Postman gives you the ability to set your own custom headers.